# How to set intellij to show logs in the logs tab and not the output tab

Tags: spring, tomcat, intellij-idea, log4j

When I use intellijs' (12.1.4) built-in tomcat the logs are being written to the output tab of the debug panel and not to a the normal localhost log tab.

I followed [this](http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/webhelp/run-debug-configuration-tomcat.html#d270744e1012) document and added my log4j.properties which works fine in the output tab but it still does write the logs to right tab.

When I pack the project and deploy it on standalone tomcat I can see the logs.

Normally I would not care but the problem with the output tab is that you can not search in it.

This is my log4j and I have tired it both with ConsoleAppender and RollingFileAppender.

```
log4j.rootLogger=TRACE, A1

log4j.appender.A1=org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.A1.File=${catalina.home}/logs/algo_js.log
log4j.appender.A1.MaxFileSize=500KB
log4j.appender.A1.MaxBackupIndex=5
log4j.appender.A1.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout

# Print the date in ISO 8601 format
log4j.appender.A1.layout.ConversionPattern=%d [%t] %-5p %c - %m%n
```

Any ideas what I am missing?

Just clarify I added a pic.
[image: the top panel is where the logs are being shown and the bottom panel is where I would like it to be displayed ... where the search is]

Answer (score 9):

In the application server Run/Debug configuration open the **Logs** tab and specify the full log file path there.

You can just search your disk for `algo_js.log` file and specify its location.