# Define log level Intellij 2016.2 (Java)

Tags: java, api, logging, intellij-idea

Good morning,

I'm using Intellij 2016.2 to run a Tomcat project.

When I run my application on Intellij in order to check/debug, it's really slow to launch (3-4 min) and I think it's because of the logging.
I see way to much logs on the Server output

[image: Screenshots of logs]

I really don't know how to make it faster and I think it's because of the logging.

No pb on my computer side, high performance, etc ...

Any idea ?

Thanks a lot
IL

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to set intellij to show logs in the logs tab and not the output tab](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17162434/how-to-set-intellij-to-show-logs-in-the-logs-tab-and-not-the-output-tab)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its not question of IDE, but logging library configuration. Idea is just displaying console output.